# Application closing without any exception while cropping image

Tags: android, image, crop

I am cropping an Image and displaying it into an Image view.

When image size is less than 350*350 , it displays correctly but when size is greater than mentioned value, the application closes silently without throwing any exception.
Can someone please figure out what is wrong? And how to tackle the situation.

I am using below code.
( I want actual cropped image. i.e. if cropped size is 20*20 then ony 20*20 is dislayed , not the stretched 200*200 every time. thats why outputX line is commented.)

```
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
            //intent.putExtra("outputX", 200); 
            //intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("circleCrop", new String(""));
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the scale parameters for your image view to avoid streching. Also for the intent remove the scale parameter and put crop instead.

```
intent.putExtra("crop", true);
```

EDIT:
The problem has to be with `intent.putExtra("return-data", true);`. I would suggest you check the `onActivityResult()` where you check for the response of the crop activity. The crash has to be due to memory limitations of returning image data for sizes greater than 350*350.

Comment: Output parameters define max dimensions? I think they define fixed output size, No matter how much you zoom in or zoom out while cropping, the size of output image will be 200*200;